# BeautifulSoup with Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm Web Scraping on Beautiful Soup and I am getting an error on line 13: for row in table.findAll('tr'). 
Its coming up an error on the cmd. Hope someone could help.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url='http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/carparks.htm'
response = requests.get(url)
html= response.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
table=soup.find('tbody', attrs={'id' :'itemsBody'})

list_of_rows=[]
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells=[]
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;','')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_cells.append(list_of_cells)

outfile= open("./carpark.csv", "wb")
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(["location","spaces"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: Please post your error.

Comment: soup=BeautifulSoup(html), Traceback(most recent call last):, File"Test.py", line 13, in <module>, for row in table.findAll('tr'), AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Comment: I was following this webpage='https://first-web-scraper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna stick to `BeautifulSoup` then you can fetch and write the content using its `xml` parser along with `csv.DictWriter()`. Check out the implementation:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/cpdata.xml?1543254514266'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,"xml")
data = []
for item in soup.select("carpark"):
    ditem = {}
    ditem['Name'] = item.get("name")
    ditem['Spaces'] = item.get("spaces")
    data.append(ditem)

with open("xmldocs.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,["Name","Spaces"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for info in data:
        writer.writerow(info)
```

Comment: :-) Plus one for you

Comment: Thanks. I love Pandas as well.

Comment: I'm learning at mo so pleased to see examples like the above. Thanks!

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much, quick question but as this is a real-time application, is there a way to have this updating itself? or will I have to do it manually?

Comment: Are you talking about the update of the csv file content? If so then you need to schedule the script using task scheduler or so.

Comment: Yep, the table updates every 5 mins or so, as I want to put the information into tableau i would love if it could update automatically.

Comment: That's a huge implementation and definitely the scope of your existing question. Try creating a new post describing your further requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could retrieve the data as an xml doc and then parse. This is just an example of part of process you could tailor.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/cpdata.xml?1543254514266'
xml_data = requests.get(url).content
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_data)
parking = []
for child in tree:
    for nextChild in child:
        parking.append([child.tag ,nextChild.attrib['name'],nextChild.attrib['spaces']])
df = pd.DataFrame(parking)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```

Comment: I've never worked with xml, I would love if the table could be put into a csv file and then I can export the information to tableau.

Comment: Updated for you.